# Unable to install packages in R - imager or igraph - mac OS

Tags: r, igraph, install.packages, imager

I've been trying to install some sort of image processor in R.

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/igraph’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘igraph’ is not available for package ‘imager’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.3/site-library/imager’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘imager’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/z9/nqzmxd4951q40m_c_n3622p80000gn/T/RtmpXt8jPq/downloaded_packages’
```

I used install.packages ("imager")
Then tried to install igraph separately. My R is 4.3.2, and my Rstudio is up to date.
I have also tried to install EBImage, and magick as alternatives.

Everything has been resulting in a "had non-zero exit status"

Any advice?

Comment: Follow igraph's installation instructions carefully: https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/?tab=readme-ov-file#installation If you still have problems, check the troubleshooting document, linked from within the installation instructions. It is not possible to say more without seeing the complete installation log.